# Power BI Embedded - Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am currently using the "App Owns Data" Web app to embed my reports,

Is it currently possible to pass parameters to the report before its loaded? I know you can pass filters but this is not sufficient for what i want to achieve.

Ideally i would like to be able to pass a parameter to my web app, then this gets passed into the report which changes the source and database name of the data being shown.

This would save having to create a new report for each system, providing we use the same SQL schema.

Any Information on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "Set parameters" API for this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt845781.aspx

POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/UpdateParameters

```
{ 
  "updateDetails": [ 
    { 
      "name": "MaxId", 
      "newValue": "5678" 
    }, 
    { 
      "name": "StrParam", 
      "newValue": "Another Hello" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Please include some code examples and clarification from the link provided (so if the link is broken, your answer will still provide a solution).